# No nvidia drivers show up under restricted drivers

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

I am running Linux Mint 16 (but my experience has been consistent across other Ubuntu derivates including Xubuntu) on a Lenovo W540. I know there have been issues with linux compatibility for this machine, but I have just now been able to run all three monitors by docking and running in "Standard" mode (BIOS setting).

However, I am unable to see any options for my nvidia card. The output of `lspci | grep -i vga` is:

```
vivin@serenity ~ $ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

But I am unable to see any drivers.

I tried installing the nvidia drivers manually (downloaded them from the NVIDIA site) but simply succeeded in ending up with a `640x480` screen and cinnamon crashing.

I haven't tried `nvidia-current` because on a previous install that simply gave me a black screen on login.

I am wondering if I should go ahead and do this anyway; I can simply change the `nvidia` driver to `nouveau` in `Xorg.conf`, right?

Is there any other way to get the OS to recognize the fact that I *do* have an NVIDIA card on my machine?

Comment: You should build binary Debian packages for the nvidia drivers for your kernel. You could use `module-assistant`, for example. It would be more accurate to describe Mint as a Debian derivative, even if not directly, since Ubuntu is itself a Debian derivative.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm new to Mint, so I am most probably wrong. But from what I read, there are two flavors: one that is built off Ubuntu (which is itself debian), and one that simply tracks Debian directly? How would I go about building the Debian packages for the nvidia binary drivers?

Comment: You're correct about the Mint flavors. However, from the pov of building debian packages for the nvidia binary drivers it is irrelevant. Just install `module-assistant`. Then fire it up, `m-a`. Then follow the menus for building and installing. It should be quite straight-forward. You want `nvidia-kernel`, I think. If you have questions pop into the main unix.sx chat room, you have enough rep. I should be around for the next hour at least.

Comment: Perhaps you should first check which version of the nvidia drivers (if any) supports your card.

Comment: @FaheemMitha why don't you post an answer?